# Does RedGard count as a rubber sealer in a shower?

Tags: concrete, shower, waterproofing

In standard poured shower pan construction there is normally a rubber layer between the bottom flat layer, and the upper sloped layer.

Today I came across the following "updated" method:

[image: redgaurd shower method]
(credit: [Mr. Money Mustache](http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/))

I am under the impression that redgaurd is used primarily to keep splashes and overflow from causing an issue, and not as a primary water repellant.

Is redgard, or any comparable product, able to hold up under this kind of abuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is what [RedGard](http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/products/surface-preparation/membranes-underlayments/redgard.aspx) is for (I assume you are planning to tile over the top of it).  It is a waterproof membrane, it stops any water that might make it through the cracks in the tile (or grout).  It is not intended to stand up to the abuse of a normal shower wall or floor so it must be covered with tile.

From the company's website:

> Rated for extra heavy duty service
>
> Meets Uniform Plumbing Code specifications for use as a shower pan liner

I used RedGard to waterpoof behind my tiles in my tub surround.  It was pretty easy to work with.

Comment: @Tester101- I tried embedding them as "pictures from the web" but it did not work because Google does not expose the actual URL of the pic itself. When I get home I will upload the originals to SE.  For now I will remove the links.